# Request Form Redirecting to Forbidden page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I followed laravel documentation about Form Request Validation.
and im not sure if get it correctly. i created a make:request EmployeeRequest to validate an employee form. but for some reasons it only redirects me to a blank page with "forbidden" as message

```
// this is my request code
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'bail|required|email|unique:employees|max:255',
        'first_name' => 'bail|required|max:50|min:2',
        'last_name' => 'bail|required|max:50|min:2',
        'date_of_birth' => 'bail|required',
        'contact_number' => 'bail|required|max:11',
        'image' => 'bail|required|image',
    ];
}

//then i called it in my controller like this
public function store(EmployeeRequest $request)
{
      //my code if everything is valid
}
```

(when entering invalid data)
it only redirects me to a blank page with an echo of forbidden.
im not sure if i understand it correctly. but im expecting that it will automatically redirects to the previous page with errors

Comment: is only with invalid data or also with valid data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have to authorize the user, or change the `authorize()` function to `return true` . From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#authorizing-form-requests):

> If the authorize method returns false, a HTTP response with a 403 status code will automatically be returned and your controller method
>   will not execute.
>
> If you plan to have authorization logic in another part of your
>   application, return true from the  authorize method:

```
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
```